# output alignment issues in c++

Tags: c++, alignment, output, c++14

I want to have these aligned but the strings are giving a problem. I have tried using left but it doesn't work here.

[image: table preview]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me guess, you're using tabs to separate the columns? The problem with this is that is has no justification (left or right), and it depends on the length of previously printed output since tabs are at fixed *positions* in the output, i.e. tabs are variable width.

If you want a fixed column width then you should use the [`std::setw`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) manipulator.

Comment: Well yes, I am using tabs.

Comment: Ill try setw and then get back

Comment: it worked! thanks :)

Comment: Then please consider *accepting* my answer. Please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) from [the help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help).